# Create a search page using ransack and route the results to the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, search-engine, ransack

I am new to RoR. I am trying to create a home/index page which will contain a search form for ransack gem. 
I am not sure how to go about it.
I have 6 models that are related to each other. I would like to create a search form and route the results back to the search page for the viewers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have already spend 4 days trying to figure it out.

Thank You

The following gets the input and then redirects me to the application/index page with search results.

applications_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter :only_allow_admin, :only => [ :index, :edit, :destroy ]

  # GET /applications
  # GET /applications.json
  def index
    @apps = Application.all
    @search = Application.search(params[:q])
    @apps = @search.result
    @search.build_condition
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @apps }
    end
  end
```

home_controller.rb

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  #before_filter :search

  def search
    # @searchphrase = "%" + params[:q] + "%"
    # @results = Database.find(:all, :conditions => [ "name LIKE ? ", @searchphrase])
    # render :layout => false
  end

  def index
    @search = Application.search(params[:q])
    @apps = @search.result
    @search.build_condition

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @apps }
    end
  end

  def about
  end

end
```

index.html.erb in home comtroller

```
<h2>Core Database</h2>
<%= javascript_include_tag "prototype" %>
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name_cont, "Name contains" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name_cont %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Search" %></div>
<% end %>

<div id="results"><% yield %></div>
```

Comment: As your question stands now, there's not much to offer that's not in the documentation for ransack. If you share what you have so far, someone may be able to point out where you went wrong.

Comment: I will put what I have till now in the answer. Also, is there any other way I could accomplish the same?